# Glib hash table issues with signal handling code

Tags: c, thread-safety, system, signals, glib

I've got some system level code that fires timers every once in a while, and has a signal handler that manages these signals when they arrive. This works fine and seems completely reasonable. There are also two separate threads running alongside the main program, but they do not share any variables, but use glib's async queues to pass messages in one direction only.

The same code uses glib's `GHashTable` to store, well, key/value pairs. When the signal code is commented out of the system, the hash table appears to operate fine. When it is enabled, however, there is a strange race condition where the call to `g_hash_table_lookup` actually returns NULL (meaning that there is no entry with the key used to look it up), when indeed the entry is actually there (yes I made sure by printing the whole list of key/value pairs with `g_hash_table_foreach`). Why would this occur most of the time? Is GLib's hash table implementation buggy? Sometimes the lookup call is successful.

It's a very particular situation, and I can clarify further if it didn't make sense, but I'm hoping I am doing something wrong so that this can actually be fixed.

More info: The code segments that are not within the signal handler scope but access the g_hash_table variable are surrounded by signal blocking calls so that the signal handler does not access these variables when the process was originally accessing them too.

Comment: When you say "The same code..." do you mean that the signal handler itself is using the GHashTable API? Or just the parallel threads?

Comment: Yes, the signal handler uses g_hash_table_remove().

Comment: You should probably not be doing hashtable work in signal handlers; check `signal(7)` for a list of safe functions that _can_ be called in signal handlers and be prepared for a fairly short list.

Comment: Oh my, that will never work reliably.

Comment: @emish you are in for a world of hurt, my friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Generally, signal handlers can only set flags and make system calls

As it happens, there are severe restrictions in ISO C regarding what signal handlers can do, and most library entry points and most API's are not even remotely 100% multi-thread-safe and approximately 0.0% of them are signal-handler-safe. That is, there is an absolute prohibition against calling almost anything from a signal handler.

In particular, for GHashTable, `g_hash_table_ref()` and `g_hash_table_unref()` are the only API elements that are even thread-safe, and none of them are signal-handler safe. Actually, ISO-C only allows signal handlers to modify objects declared with `volatile sig_atomic_t` and only a couple of library routines may be called.

Some of us consider threaded systems to be intrinsically dangerous, practically radioactive sources of subtle bugs. A good place to start worrying is [The Problem with Threads.](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-1.html) (And note that signal handlers themselves are much worse. No one thinks an API is safe there...)